# xml parser PostgreSQL 6G

Tags: xml, parsing, postgresql

Everyday, we need to to parse around 60,000 xml files into 3 tables in PostgreSQL or mysql
 database. Size of each file is about 50-300k. There are 10  types of message. Each file  has messages of different types. What method or tool to use to make the parsing robust, efficient ?

Comment: Downvoted because it's way too broad to answer in its current form; see @gahooa's answer, which is mostly "we need more detail".

Answer (score 1):

I'd use Perl, [Mojo::DOM](http://search.cpan.org/~sri/Mojolicious/lib/Mojo/DOM.pm), [DBIx::Connector](http://search.cpan.org/~dwheeler/DBIx-Connector/lib/DBIx/Connector.pm), and PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to approach this problem.  Parsing XML is not a unique problem -- and almost any decent language can do it.

What platform are you on?

What languages are you most familiar with?

As far as **robust**, Python is an excellent language with good error handling, very flexible, fast to develop, easy to maintain.

If you choose python, you will want to use a c-based xml extension for speed.  Take a look at http://lxml.de/, or perhaps ElementTree is backed by a c module in some versions.

More details would prompt better answers.